# Neo4j find all that match X but don't match Y

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a simple domain of Students and Courses. A student can be registered for multiple courses.

I want to **find all students registered for course 1234 that were not registered for course 5678**.

So I tried this attempt:

```
MATCH (s:Student)
MATCH (c:Course)
MATCH (s)-[r:REGISTRATION]->(c {code: "1234"})
WHERE NOT (s)-[r:REGISTRATION]->(c {code: "5678"})
RETURN s
```

But it seems like the last `WHERE NOT` makes no difference to the query? I can still find students from the query result that are also registered for the second course :/

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
MATCH (sUnwnated:Student)-[r:REGISTRATION]->(:Course{code: "5678"}) // get all students in "5678"
WITH COLLECT(sUnwnated) AS sUnwnated // group them to a list                
MATCH (sWanted:Student)-[r:REGISTRATION]->(:Course{code: "1234"}) // get all students in "1234"
WHERE NOT sWanted IN sUnwnated // but keep only these that are not in the list
RETURN sWanted
```

Comment: First I got the error "Invalid input 'N'..." at "where swanted Not in sunwnated". After a quick googling I think it should be `WHERE NOT sWanted IN sUnwnated`. After fixing that I got the error "Type mismatch: expected List<T> but was Node".

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer

Comment: Is it working for you now?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was missing only one important keyword/function, [exists()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/predicate/#functions-exists).

This works:

```
MATCH (s:Student)
MATCH (c:Course)
MATCH (s)-[r:REGISTRATION]->(c {code: "1234"})
WHERE NOT exists((s)-[r:REGISTRATION]->(c {code: "5678"}))
RETURN s
```